# Filtering data in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is some data:

```
record
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | name                                |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Round Cookie                        |
| 2       | Square Cookie                       |
| 3       | Oval Cookie                         |
| 4       | Hexagon Cookie                      |
-------------------------------------------------

record_field_data
----------------------------------------------
| id      | record_id | data       | type_id |
----------------------------------------------
| 1       | 1         | White      | 1       |
| 2       | 1         | Round      | 2       |
| 3       | 2         | Green      | 1       |
| 4       | 2         | Square     | 2       |
| 5       | 3         | Blue       | 1       |
| 6       | 3         | Oval       | 2       |
| 7       | 4         | Hexagon    | 2       |
----------------------------------------------

record_type_field
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | data_type                           |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Color                               |
| 2       | Shape                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to get a list of all records left joined with the record_field_data of type "Color". This needs to be a left join because there may not be record_field_data of a given type, and I still want the record if the case.

This is the query I have come up with but it is returning a left join with ALL record_field_data and not just the specific ones I want.

```
SELECT record.id AS id, recordfield.data, recordtype.field_name
FROM record
LEFT JOIN record_field_data AS recordfield ON (record.id = recordfield.record_id)
LEFT JOIN record_type_field AS recordtype ON (recordfield.type_id = recordtype.id AND recordtype.data_type = 'Color');
```

I could do this with a subquery in the JOIN but I can't use a subquery. I have to translate this to HQL and subqueries are not supported in HQL for joins.

The result I am looking for is records ordered by the record_field_data where record_type_field.data_type is 'Color'. Note that "Hexagon cookie" doesn't have a color defined, I don't know if it should be at the top or bottom at this point. Either way will work.

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    | id      | name                                |
    -------------------------------------------------
    | 3       | Oval Cookie                         |
    | 2       | Square Cookie                       |
    | 1       | Round Cookie                        |
    | 4       | Hexagon Cookie                      |
    -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the results that you are looking for.

Comment: Added the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  r.id, r.name
FROM    record r
JOIN    record_type_field rf
ON      rf.data_type = 'Color'
LEFT JOIN
        record_type_data rd
ON      rd.record_id = r.id
        AND rd.type_id = rf.id
ORDER BY
        rd.data
```

Comment: [**Working Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df61a/4) my logic was wrong +1 for you

Comment: This works...unfortunately I don't think I can do this in HQL either. :(

Comment: @Quassnoi: The problem is that HQL doesn't support ON directives for joins. Joins are predetermined by the entity model so whatever I do has to fit within that structure. I tried to come up with a HQL query similar to this query but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SQL 'IN' clause.

```
select record.id as id, recordfield.data, recordtype.field_name
from record
left join record_field_data recordfield ON record.id = recordfield.record_id
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM record_type_field where data_type='Color');
```

The IN clause allows you to specify a list condition. So the subquery gets all of the ids where the type is "Color", and you are then doing the join and selecting all records from that join that have an id in the list of ids corresponding to the type "Color".

Comment: A where clause will filter out records which do not have a color assigned to them.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the second join to a `INNER JOIN`.

If you use two `LEFT JOIN`s you are selecting all the records from `record` **AND** from `record_field_data`.

Comment: `...This needs to be a left join because there may not be record_field_data of a given type...`